# Why php script may stop?

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I'm running really long task in php. It's a website crawler and It has to be polite and sleep for 5 seconds each page to prevent server overloading. Script starts with:

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
session_write_close();
ob_end_clean();
while (@ob_end_flush());
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

After few hours (between 3-7h) script dies without any visible reason. 
I've checked

- apache error log (nothing)
- php_errors.log (nothing)
- output for errors (10 578 467b of debug output, no errors)
- memory consumption (stable, around 3M from `memory_get_usage(true)` checked every 5 sec, limit set to 512M)

It's not browser, cause I was using wget and chrome to check with the similar reason. 
Output is sent to browser every 2-3 seconds, so I don't think that's the fault + I ignore user abort.

Is there any other place I can check to find the issue?

Comment: If it's running inside the apache container (mod_php) I can imagine it will eventually kill off the process without notifying you :)

Comment: Can you run it standalone (outside of Apache)?

Comment: how about doing this in parts? scan 500-1000 links, then call the same script with some parameter to start with an offset

Comment: Is this to be controlled by a cron? If so, I'd suggest forcing the script to run for a set time and then use the cron to restart it shortly afterwards (If you can't find out what's killing it now and prevent it)

Comment: phpinfo shows CGI/FastCGI, so my guess is suPHP. I don't want to run it via cron, cause it's task-driven tool. First seconds of process are important to user - should script be restarted with different config, or keep running. Waiting for cron to start it isn't very usable.

Comment: Without more information on the actual code you're using, would it be possible to restart the script as part of the general process every now and then, using a marker to see where you were up to and carrying on? Relying on a script to run for hours at end with no fall back to continue after a crash seems like a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem in the rest of your script, not Apache.

Try profiling your application using the [register_tick_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) with a light profiler like [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) and logging the [memory usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php), may be that.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. Script should end with either "finished" message or some kind of error. I double checked the entire file for `exit`, `die` and `return` that would give no message, but there are none. And I've checked memory usage (read the question).