# php stops working while executing a long running script

Tags: php, sockets, iis

I have a long execution php script that has to run for several hours, but after 10 to 20 min. the script stops generating output but the page is still on execution time. When I refresh the page it will continue to generate the output. After several refreshes the php stops generating any output. I am using sockets in the script and all the timeouts have been set for 24 hours.

Comment: you really shouldn't run a process that requires that amount of time  via http, it should be run on the command line (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Comment: I tried to run it using CMD but it's the same thing. And there is nothing wrong with the code it's working correctly. @Dagon

Comment: @user754282 I don't see how it can have the same result run on the command line as, there's no browser, and that paid a part in the original question , need more details here.

Answer (score 0):

I asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194187/why-php-script-may-stop) a while ago, and still got no answer, however you can try looking into:

- your apache error log
- your php_error log file (set it in php.ini, or just by using `ini_set` at beginning of your code)
- log your memory consumption - it may be the reason.

Comment: Thanks @Smok I think It's from memory consumption and CPU usage. After a while (12 min ) my script stop producing the output and the explorer.exe CPU usage reaches %25 together with the php.exe the CPU usage became %25. and when I terminate the script the CPU usage still at %25 but after a while it became normal. Why is this happening?

Comment: 25% is most likely 100% of one of four cores of your CPU. It means that PHP is consuming entire core for itself. After killing this process it needs time to calculate all the queued tasks and free up allocated memory. You have to put `sleep()` or `usleep()` here and there (inside main loop?) to allow other processes to use that core.